# In webdatarocks pivot table, how can i get the date to be split into Year / Month / Day by local time?

Tags: webdatarocks

The date for the entry below will be split by the pivot table to 2022, June, 30 but I need it to be 2022 July 1 when viewed in UTC+10.  How can this be achieved without fudging (time shifting) the input date field?

```
  {
    "name": "Fred",
    "duration": 33.2,
    "date": "2022-06-30T23:55:50.298Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way of displaying the date in your timezone is preprocessing data before passing it to the pivot table by removing `Z` from the date value.